# android board game

Tags: android

I want to create a board game (9x9 grid) for the android. I was wondering if there where any suggestions as to books, blogs, tutorial, or even open source programs to look into.

I was planning on writing the majority of it in native java/c++. probably with a target of API level7 platform 2.1 update 1 (as this is an actual device I have access to)

I am mostly interested in displaying the board, tiles, and pieces (I already have a some assets that can be re-sized if needed) to the screen, and if I can find something that will help me understand how to register movement of the pieces that would be amazing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [Hello, Android](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356565) guides you through the development of a game which has a 9x9 grid, Sudoku. The author's implementation of the grid is simple and easy to follow. The book is a decent read for beginners.

Comment: thank you with what I've seen already seems like it will be helpful

Comment: Yeah it's a useful read if you are just starting out. Once you have learned more about 2D graphics in Android the steps necessary to creating the game you have in mind will become more obvious.